# html5 canvas doesn't fill text at coordinates (0,0)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Why does the canvas not do anything for `fillText(text, 0,0)` but works for `fillText(text, 10, 10)`?

`fillText(text, 0,0):` http://jsfiddle.net/kFhQm/4/

`fillText(text, 10, 10):` http://jsfiddle.net/kFhQm/5/

Comment: What would you expect it to show?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The second argument is the Y coordinate for the baseline of the text (the default `textBaseline` is `"alphabetic"`)
, so the text is being drawn *above* the visible `canvas` element when you use `0`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRVYq/).

You could use a different number or alternatively, change the `textBaseline` property to something suitable, such as `"top"`.

```
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LY5wS/).

Comment: Setting the baseline to "top" forced the expected behavior of positioning text starting from (x, y). Thanks!

Comment: fyi the context.textBaseline parameters are as follows:
`"top", "middle", "bottom"`, then there's `"hanging"` and `"alphabetic"(default)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline